# Can't exec NSIS installation application from tcl script

Tags: windows, tcl, nsis

Running **tcl 8.4.13**, I have a tcl script to execute my NSIS installation application (duly signed by microsoft) that used to work but now fails (windows 7 and 10), maybe because of windows security update or something? The same tcl script works fine when the target is a local/renamed copy of notepad.exe. The NSIS application works fine when run from from the command line.

The tcl script looks like the following, run via **tclkit-win32 tclmnu.tcl**, where tclmnu.tcl looks like this:

```
#! /bin/sh -x
# \
    exec wish "$0" "$@"
#

package require Tk

#set runcmd notepad_local_copy.exe
set runcmd my_nsis_app.exe  # this doesn't work

# this works with the notepad_local_copy.exe (above) but not my_nsis_app.exe
set catchcode [ catch { exec ${runcmd} } result ]

# also tried this, doesn't work either
#set catchcode [ catch { exec "runas /usr:administrator: ${runcmd}" } result ]

tk_messageBox -type ok -icon error -message "DEBUG: catchcode=${catchcode}"
# catchcode is 0 when runas=notepad_local_copy.exe, 1 when it's my_nsis_app.exe
```

Comment: Does your installer require elevation?

Comment: That's why I tried the runas (commented out above) which has the same result. But running cmd /c fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by adding cmd /c, as in

```
set catchcode [ catch { cmd /c exec ${runcmd} } result ]
```

I don't know why it needs that, nor why it seemed to work before and not now.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like the problem was that it needs to run in the right subsystem and the one picked by default by Windows was the wrong one. Which is horrible if true, but not wholly unbelievable; subprocess execution on Windows has a number of truly awful gotchas hidden in it (at the OS API level) and those things can only be partially hidden.

Comment: @DonalFellows This has nothing to do with the subsystem, CreateProcess can mix and match those two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about TCL but I'm assuming that `exec` calls [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa). When UAC was added to Vista it seems Microsoft deemed `CreateProcess` too low-level to be able to perform elevation.

> **[Dealing with Administrator and standard user’s context:](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2010/05/31/dealing-with-administrator-and-standard-users-context/)**
>
> `CreateProcess` and `CreateProcessWithLogonW` do not have new flags to launch the child process as elevated.  Internally, CreateProcess() checks whether the target application requires elevation by looking for a manifest, determining if it is an installer, or if it has an app compat shim.  **If CreateProcess() determines the target application requires elevation, it simply fails with ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED(740).**  It will not contact the AIS to perform the elevation prompt or run the app.  If CreateProcess() determines the application doesn’t require elevation, it will spawn it as a new process.

`ShellExecute[Ex]` however is able to contact the UAC service and display the UAC elevation dialog:

> To programmatically launch a child process as an elevated process, two things must occur: first, the executable of the child process needs to be identified as needing elevation, and second, the parent process needs to use ShellExecute() or ShellExecuteEx().

It seems there are multiple ways to get TCL to call `ShellExecute`:

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] {""} [list [file nativename $filename]] ;# http://wiki.tcl.tk/2809
```

or

```
twapi::shell_execute -path filename.exe ;# http://www.magicsplat.com/blog/how-do-i-exec-thee/
```

You can also request elevation of executables even if they are not marked as requiring elevation:

```
twapi::shell_execute -path filename.exe -verb runas
```

(The `runas` [verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-verbs) is not the same thing as `runas.exe`)

NSIS scripts use the `RequestExecutionLevel` attribute to mark the executable with the desired UAC elevation level.

Using `cmd /c` is a bit of a hack and will probably display a console window for a brief period of time. `cmd /c` first tries CreateProcess and then falls back to `ShellExecuteEx` if elevation was required. I'm not sure if this is documented behavior.

Comment: I was thinking it might flash up a console but I'm not seeing one (or not noticeable)... no matter, it works well enough and the application is approaching EOL in any case.